# Listen for children count of an element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, browser

I am using jquery and I want to execute a function after counting the number of children of an element.
My element has a child and I want to execute a function after it became 2 or more.
This child appending is handled by some other JavaScript file and I just want to listen for adding a child in that element.
That append child happens after an async operation so it may not be executed at the time of checking children count.
Here is what I tried:

```js
let i = 0;
const interVal = setInterval(() => {
    const parent = $(".parent");

    if (parent && parent.length > 1) {
        console.log("Child has been appended.");
    } else {
        console.log("Child has not been appended!");

        if (i >= 50000) {
            console.error("A lot of conditions executed and cannot bother browser anymore.");

            clearInterval(interVal);
        }
    }

    i++;
}, 1);
```

This code has a problem.
It is checking after a period of time.
What can I replace with it?

Comment: Please show us your code and what you have tried please

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please take the time to read the [tour] and [ask] pages.

Answer (score 2):

[MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#example) is what you need.

Here is the MDN example very slightly modified.

```js
// simulating some content appended in a later time (async)
setTimeout(function () {
  $(".parent").append("<div>I am a div appended after page load!</div>");
}, 5000);

// Mutation observer
var targetNode = $(".parent")[0];

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
const callback = function (mutationsList, observer) {
  // Use traditional 'for loops' for IE 11
  for (const mutation of mutationsList) {
    if (mutation.type === "childList") {
      console.log("A child node has been added or removed.");

      // How many children now?
      console.log(`There is ${$(".parent").children().length} child elements`);
      
      // List them
      $(".parent").children().each(function(index){
        console.log(`#${index+1}- ${$(this)[0].tagName} - ${$(this)[0].innerText}`)
      })
      
    } else if (mutation.type === "attributes") {
      console.log("The " + mutation.attributeName + " attribute was modified.");
    }
  }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <h1>Hello! Another child will be appended...</h1>
</div>
```

To put an end to the `observer`... Like if a condition is reached at some point... Use:

```
observer.disconnect();
```

Comment: If you want to just listen to direct child changes, don't include subtree option to the config

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's all about if-else.

Let me explain it to you.

```
<div id="parent">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

to reach the count of children, you should use .length like this;

```
var count = $("#parent li").length;
```

or this way

```
var count = $("#parent ul").children().length;
```

Now let's say you want to execute if the count of children is bigger than 2 or whatever you want;

```
if(count>2){
    alert("I am bigger than 2, mate");
}
```

Comment: That child appending happens after an async operation. So maybe it is not appended in that time.